# How to help our 4-year-old who can't bite food into appropriately sized pieces?

Tags: pre-schooler, development, eating, teaching

My almost 4-year-old won’t bite his food. He doesn’t seem to know how to. If given a large piece of food, he will try to stuff the whole piece in his mouth or won’t even try to eat it because of its size.

For instance, when given a full cookie, he doesn’t bite it. Instead, he will either try to put the whole cookie in his mouth or just look at it and, as he seems to know that it won’t fit, push it aside and not eat it. Sometimes, he gets upset and wants it broken into smaller pieces so he can eat it. We have tried to help him but he just doesn’t seem to get it. He is a good eater and has no trouble chewing or swallowing.

We do eat as a family, but he doesn’t model after the adults and he won’t bite even soft foods. We repeatedly demonstrate how to bite to no avail. He has never attempted to bite anything, we believe it isn’t his teeth. He is also slow to talk and has been having speech therapy since he was 2 1/2, so even though he is communicating more he is still delayed.

**How can we help him learn to bite food into smaller pieces he can then eat?**

Comment: Hello Marcy. Thank you for posting and welcome to Parenting.SE. Can you clarify a little bit? He doesn't bite his food when sticks in his mouth?

Comment: If given a large piece of food he will try to stuff the whole piece in his mouth or won’t even try to eat it because of its size. For instance, when given a full cookie he doesn’t bite it so it will either try to put the whole cookie in his mouth or just look at it and seems to know that it won’t fit so will push it aside and won’t eat it. Sometimes he gets upset and wants it broke into smaller pieces so he can eat it. FYI he is slow to talk and has been having speech therapy since he was 2 1/2 so even though he is communicating more he is still delayed.

Comment: Sorry I tried to edit my post but it said I couldn’t. So after for instance.. he doesn’t bite it so it will be easier to chew. He will either...

Comment: Hi Marcy. Welcome! Did you know that speech therapists also work with children to help them eat properly? I would suggest you mention this to your speech therapist and see if your has an eating issue.  He may have to be taught to bite and eat properly. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check into that. He was having speech therapy at home until he turned 3 then he was enrolled in state sponsored preschool at our area elementary school. He is getting speech therapy there as well as other preschool curriculum. They have snacks there but it is usually finger snacks so not sure she would know of this problem. Will definitely check on this.

Comment: First of all, I hope you are okay with my edit! Just a thought, but maybe it's worth asking: Might there be a problem with his teeth, especially the incisors? I just wondered, since he can chew (but may rather use (pre-)molars for that). Maybe it hurts and so he avoids using them to bite off smaller pieces. Did you show him how to do it?

Comment: @suse That looks like a good answer, to me!

Comment: Thank you Anne. He actually does have problems with his front teeth. Not that we’ve noticed any sensitivity problems but his front teeth have had a brown discoloration to them since he was 2. We brush his teeth every night and the discoloration lightens but darkens again. That’s definitely something to check into.

Comment: Do you typically eat together as a family?  Does he respond to adults modeling or exaggerating biting into foods, or manage to bite off a part from softer foods (like a banana)?

Answer (score 1):

We have requested the speech teacher works with him on this, as well as drinking from a cup, and she is planning to start helping with the biting. She is already working with him on drinking from a cup.